# get data from controller function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony

I would like to get and post data using jquery / ajax in symfony.

What I have done :

in my javascript file :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#get').click(getB);
});

function getB() {
    var route = $('#ajaxGetRoute').val();
    route = route.substring(0, route.length - 1) + "19";

    $.get(route, function(){
        alert("test");
    });
}
```

Here, route represents a url to go to my controller function.

My controller function :

```
$isAjax = $request->isXMLHttpRequest();
if ($isAjax) {
    $myRepository= $this
        ->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('MyBundle:MyEntity');

    $content = $myRepository->findById($id)->getContent();
    return new Response($content);
}
return new Response('This is not ajax!', 400);
}
```

When I click on the button, I can see the request is sent, but I have this error:

```
GET http://localhost/My/Url/Defined/19 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

19 is an example of `id`.

What did I do wrong? Thanks for your answers

Comment: What is the actual error? Error 500 is just the HTTP error

Comment: Humm.... I don't see any other informations about the error :-/

Comment: What error do you see when you navigate to your specified URL from the address bar?

Comment: It could be an error in the code inside the `if`, so you don't see it when you call the page from the address bar, but you see it when you call it using AJAX. What happens when you comment the `if` (not the content, just the `if($isAjax) {` and its closing `}`) and call it from the address bar?

Comment: Also, do you have any routing information? (routing.yml etc.)

Comment: Ok, when I remove the if ($isAjax) it works... Do I need to replace it by anything else ?